# Why are gravitational forces much weaker than electrostatic while both the graviton and photon are massless?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-gravity, bosons

I know that in quantum mechanics the stronger the force, the shorter the range it mediates between (maybe I have problem in this postulation, if so please correct me). So how can gravitational forces be much weaker than electrostatic forces while both the graviton and photon are massless?

Maybe I have a problem understanding the relation between boson properties and the strongness of the force it mediates, can someone explain to me please if I have a problem with the basics.

Comment: Related/possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126967/50583 and its linked questions

Comment: There is no such rule.

Comment: It's true that the weak nuclear force is "weak" compared to electromagnetism due to the fact that the W and Z bosons are massive, but there are other ways a force can be weak without having massive bosons

Comment: More on weakness of gravity: see links in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/570443/226902

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Massless (gauge) bosons only mean that the force is long-ranged, but have nothing to do with how strong the force is.

Understanding why the gravitational force is much weaker than the electromagnetic force (or any forces in a gauge theory) is still an open problem, but attempts to understand this are usually referred to as the "Weak Gravity Conjecture" (WGC). Here is the [original WGC paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0601001). There have been more recent attempts to derive the WGC from sensible physical principles like unitarity, causality, etc.